# PhpStorm unable to resolve symbol 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager'

Tags: phpstorm

When I open the services.xml in PhpStorm  with [Symfony Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pr=&pluginId=7219) enabled, it's able to resolve all the services, I can <kbd>Ctrl+Click</kbd> and go the Service Definition , except `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`.

It says unable to resolve symbol 'doctrine.orm.entity_manager'

Here is the services.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <service id="example_manager" class="Vendor\XysBundle\Manager\ExampleManager">
           <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

PhpStorm Details:

```
PhpStorm 2016.3.1
Build #PS-163.9735.1, built on December 6, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-408-b2 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

`appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml` file exists in the app/cache directory .

How can I get get this working ?

Comment: This has to be an issue with Symfony plugin as it is the one that provides such navigation/resolution -- PhpStorm just uses this info when you perform your `Ctrl+Click` action. Try checking existing issues in plugin's Issue Tracker: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20doctrine.orm.entity_manager%20

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. If you open up the `vendor\doctrine\doctrine-bundle\Resources\config\orm.xml` file where doctrine services are defined, you can see, there is no service with the id "`doctrine.orm.entity_manager`" but only "`doctrine.orm.entity_manager.abstract`"

The definition looks like:

```
<service id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager.abstract" class="%doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class%" abstract="true" />
```

As you can see the abstract attribute is set to true. This means this service can serve as a parent of other services, and when you define child services with this abstract parent you don't have to define the method calls or the parameters injected into the constructor for example, instead these definitions will be inherited from the parent.

If you investigate a bit deeper you will find that `%doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class%` is defined in the same file as a parameter that actually references to the Doctrine Entity Manager:

```
<parameter key="doctrine.orm.entity_manager.class">Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager</parameter>
```

So I guess we should use `doctrine.orm.entity_manager.abstract`, however `doctrine.orm.entity_manager` is recognised as well, although I don't know how.

For further explanation of abstract service definitions have a look at this Symfony doc page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html